# how do i remove white spaces around an image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use this image as part of the navigation bar, but the problem is there are big white spaces around the image and I cant remove it. I've tried setting the `margin` and `padding` to 0, it doesn't work.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

**UPDATE: HTML & CSS CODE**

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCR1E.png)

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhggf.png)

**2ND UPDATE**

I finally solved the problem guys.. thank you to everyone who helped!

Comment: Put your code here to know what you done already

Comment: Either the image itself has big white spaces, or the navigation menu items have margins. Post code or we're just guessing

Comment: HTML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCR1E.png
CSS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhggf.png

Comment: the image doesn't have big white spaces

Comment: have you tried set the width and height of the image?

Comment: yes, but it still doesn't work

Comment: May be its a `PNG` image with a lot of space or you have code for image width and height...it would be better you put the code here

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Almira using the `background-size` & `background-position` properties together can help you achieve exactly this, for more info see my answer below.

Comment: @Almira post your code directly on StackOverflow, otherwise we'll have to read it of an image, which could make potential helpers ignore the question. Anyways welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: The problem I suspect is the `width: 5%;` and `height: 10%;` set on your `img.feedback`. Image is resizing itself to some parent container probably the `body`. Can't say for sure without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS and play around with the `background-size` & `background-position` properties, like this:

```css
div.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOO9j.png');
  background-size: 700px 700px;
  background-position: 419px 438px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Using the Gimp Image Editor I have cropped your original image and used that as the background instead, this is what it looks like:

```css
div.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaYMF.png');
  background-size: 120%;
  background-position: 112px 115px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

The image you provided above is way too large, meaning that when you crop it the cropped image will be a low quality image. I'm sure it would be far easier and if you used a software like Gimp Image Editor or Photoshop to modify your image your self to get the specific image you wanted down to the pixel and you could simplify the my CSS to get this:

```
div.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOO9j.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**NOTE**: the red border is used to help you better see where the image is.
**NOTE**: the red border is **not** required to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to crop the image. Otherwise you can make use of CSS.

For example:

```
 <style>
    img {
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(0px,60px,250px,10px);
    }
</style>
```